# how to customize Angular Ui bootstrap tabs similar to angular material tabs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Angular Ui Bootrstrap.

```html
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
<head>
  
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.4.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script>
  angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
 angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('tranCntrl', ['$scope', function ($scope){
   
}]);
  </script>
  
  
</head>
<body ng-controller="tranCntrl">
  
<div class="panel-body">
<uib-tabset>
       <uib-tab>
             <uib-tab-heading><b> Cpu uilization </b></uib-tab-heading>
       </uib-tab>
       <uib-tab>
             <uib-tab-heading><b> memory utilization </b></uib-tab-heading>
       </uib-tab>
       <uib-tab>
             <uib-tab-heading><b> I/O waits </b></uib-tab-heading>
       </uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

but my requirement is [more like angular material tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIFK6.png)
please any one assist me in how can i do the customization for my code with out using angular material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one of two options, both aren't the best of practices but since you are trying to change a library styling these are your options.

1. You could download the UI-bootstrap css, host it yourself and edit it.
2. You you add css to your file to overwrite the style using the `!important` tag. (this is not great but if you are only overwriting a few classes that are specific to that one library its ok)

Below i have showed an example of what number 2 would look like.

```html
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
<head>
  
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.4.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script>
  angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
 angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('tranCntrl', ['$scope', function ($scope){
   
}]);
  </script>

  <style>
    .nav-tabs, .nav-tabs>li>a {
       border: 0 !important;
    }
    .uib-tab.active {
       border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    
  </style> 
</head>
<body ng-controller="tranCntrl">
  
<div class="panel-body">
<uib-tabset>
       <uib-tab>
             <uib-tab-heading><b> Cpu uilization </b></uib-tab-heading>
       </uib-tab>
       <uib-tab>
             <uib-tab-heading><b> memory utilization </b></uib-tab-heading>
       </uib-tab>
       <uib-tab>
             <uib-tab-heading><b> I/O waits </b></uib-tab-heading>
       </uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd add option 3 is just not relying on ui-bootstrap and using the bootstrap tools to make your own directive (not a huge lift in this case).

Comment: Thanks, it helps me alot